# Password md5 authentication failed when trying to connect to PostgreSQL db with php

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Environnement configuration :

- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- PostgreSQL 9.5.4
- PHP 7.0

Hi, I try to connect to my postgresql db with **php PDO**

```
$DB_ADDR="127.0.0.1";
$DB_PORT="5432";
$DB_NAME="bddautfreq";
$DB_USR="postgres";
$DB_PWD="xxx";

try{
  $bdd=new PDO ("pgsql:host=".$DB_ADDR.";port=".$DB_PORT.";dbname='".$DB_NAME."'",$DB_USR,"'".$DB_PWD."'");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur connexion BDD: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

but this error occurs :

```
Erreur connexion BDD: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

With **trust** in my pg_hba.conf file the connection is ok

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

but not with a **md5** authentication.

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

The php7.0-pgsql module is installed and enabled :

```
gbdd@GBDD-HP:~$ ls /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/
calendar.ini  fileinfo.ini  iconv.ini    pdo.ini        phar.ini      shmop.ini    sysvsem.ini
ctype.ini     ftp.ini       json.ini     pdo_pgsql.ini  posix.ini     sockets.ini  sysvshm.ini
exif.ini      gettext.ini   opcache.ini  pgsql.ini      readline.ini  sysvmsg.ini  tokenizer.ini
```

Encryption password is **on** on my **postgresql.conf** file.

Connection with **psql** is ok

```
gbdd@GBDD-HP:~/bdd$ psql -U postgres -d bddautfreq
psql (9.5.4)
Type "help" for help.

bddautfreq=#
```

I'm sure to enter the good password (same as .pgpass). For me **trust** is not a secure solution. Could someone help me to understand the error of my apache, php or postgresql configuration ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: are you converting your password to md5 while connecting to db?

Comment: I tried but not result. It seems that PDO automaticaly encrypts the password.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` extension.

Install `php-pgsql` and or enable it in **php.ini** by adding

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: This extension is yet installed. If I'm right, to enable it on linux system, it just need to find it in the mods-available directory.

Comment: **$** `sudo phpenmod php_pdo_pgsql`

Comment: is pdo_pgsql the same extension than php_pdo_pgsql ? Because only pdo_pgsql.ini exists under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from PHP side. All authentication problems comes from the single quotes I put on both sides of the password variable.

In php5 the following syntax run properly (the one I had on an other server) :

```
$bdd=new PDO ("pgsql:host=".$DB_ADDR.";port=".$DB_PORT.";dbname='".$DB_NAME."'",$DB_USR,"'".$DB_PWD."'");
```

But in php7, it needs to delete all "'" like that :

```
$bdd=new PDO ("pgsql:host=".$DB_ADDR.";port=".$DB_PORT.";dbname=$DB_NAME,$DB_USR,$DB_PWD);
```

Even if I found myself my error, I'd like to congratulate the community for the quick support !

Comment: there is a quoting issue in the php7 version